# how to embed pretty json format to html static page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I have this code:

```
 public <T> String toJson(T item)
    {
        String json;
        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        try {
            json = ow.writeValueAsString(item);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            json = "";
        }
        return json;
    }
```

I create a static html page form the server side (using `gagawa`):

```
    java.util.Map<String, String> paramsMap = filterInterestingQueryParams(url);

    Li li4 = new Li().appendText("special params: " + jsonParser.toJson(paramsMap));
```

and yet my html looks broken.

How would you prettify that map into html?

*is there a way to limit line content by #chars?
*a way to persist the pretty print?

[image]

Comment: What's broken about the HTML?

Comment: the line is too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to add some CSS to your page:

```css
li.wrap {
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Really long special params: {stickToPath=8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,}</li>
<li class="wrap">Really long special params (that wraps): {stickToPath=8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,8484.20202002,-481737.45454,}</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, the second `li` with the `wrap` class wraps at the frame edge, while the other doesn't.

---

If you need the json to be pretty print you'll need to modify your output HTML and wrap the json in `<pre>` tags. By default these will retain line breaks and spaces.

Comment: thanks. btw is there a way to preserve json pretty print?